# How does GitHub project pages work?

Tags: git, github

New to git, I recently created a project page for my personal page by creating a gh-pages "orphan branch." I expected my project at the project-page-name.github.io to be basically based off the gh-pages branch that I created. However, it seems that when the master branch and gh-pages branch don't have the same file, my project page becomes confused. Why is this? (apologies for not using technical terms)

Appreciate any insight or advice! Thank you.

Comment: "I expected my project at the project-page-name.github.io to be basically based off the gh-pages branch that I created" - I don't get this sentence.

Comment: I think he means the contents of his gh-pages should build his project page? so if there was an index.html file in the gh-pages branch then that is what his projects page would display?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the URL of your GitHub page has the following form:

```
http://<username>.github.io/<repo_name>
```

And what GitHub Pages does, is it statically hosts the contents of the `gh-pages` branch, which is independent of the `master` or any other branch.

Thus if you have an `index.html` in your root directory of your `gh-pages` branch, you will have it rendered in your browser when you request the appropriate URL. Moreover, if you have `any_other_file.name` and request `http://<username>.github.io/<repo_name>/any_other_file.name` you will get it as well.

So you can treat GitHub Pages as a simple static hosting. Although, it support some configuration, like e.g. having you page behind a `CNAME` DNS record.

Comment: are gh-pages static? depending on your definition of static, this is my [gh-pages example](http://hattricknz.github.io/minicourse-ajax-project/), don't think I would call it static?

Comment: by static, I mean it is not possible to generate the pages dynamically on the server side, i.e. GitHub, thus they are just served statically. Your example is also static, all the dynamic stuff is done on the client side.